# Dynamic shell script with single and double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quotes

I am trying to make the below command by passing runtime arguments

```
host=10.130.21.182
user=test-lftp
cert=/tools/abc/a200338-ivon.ppk

lftp sftp://$user:@$host -e 'set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i $cert"'
```

But the final command is like below which is incorrect

```
lftp sftp://test-lftp:@10.130.21.182 -e 'set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i $cert"'
```

Please help me to generate the expected below command

```
lftp sftp://test-lftp:@10.130.21.182 -e 'set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i /tools/abc/a200338-ivon.ppk"'
```

Comment: This worked for me :   lftp sftp://${user}:@${host} -e 'set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i '${cert}'"'

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes don't expand variables so you have to chage it in

```
lftp sftp://test-lftp:@10.130.21.182 -e "set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program \"ssh -a -x -i $cert\""
```

Comment: lftp sftp://${user}:@${host} -e 'set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i '${cert}'"'

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
host=10.130.21.182
user=test-lftp
cert=/tools/abc/a200338-ivon.ppk

lftp sftp://$user:@$host -e 'set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1; set sftp:connect-program '"ssh -a -x -i $cert"
```

Inside single quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception:

```
foo="bar"

echo 'baz "$foo"'
echo 'baz '"$foo"
```

Will print:

```
baz "$foo"
baz bar
```